# Excel with lookup in multiple columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have an Excel file where Sheet 1 contains Playername (column A), Rank (column B), CallsAttended (column C) and Performance (Column D). Sheet 2 contains Rank (column A), Min (Column B) and Max (Column C).

Below are the tables

[image: Sheet 1]

```
Playername  Rank    CallsAttended   Performance
Person1     1000    30000           Good
Preson2     15000   2000            Good
Person3     5000    500             Good
```

[image: Sheet 2]

```
Rank    Min    Max
1000    200    900
5000    300    1000
9000    400    1100
13000   500    1200
```

Now I want to have a formula that if rank = 1000 and call attended is >= than Min and =< than Max print "good", if it is below Min print "improve" and if above Max print "Excellent" in Performance column in Sheet 1.

My formula is strictly for same row as below and I know it is not what I what to achieve.

> =IF(AND(B2=Sheet2!A2,C2<=Sheet2!B2),"Improve","Good")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a nested IF with two VLOOKUPS.

```
=IF(C2<VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet2!A:C,2,TRUE),"Improve",IF(C2<VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet2!A:C,3,TRUE),"Good","Excellent"))
```

Comment: You are genius. I will try to learn more about this i am still trying to understand how you created it but should be able to figure it out after bunch of try. This works perfect for me

Comment: @miteshpatel please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The formola -

```
=IF(C2>=VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet2!A2:C6,2,FALSE),IF(C2>=VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet2!A2:C6,3,FALSE),"Excellent","Good"),"Improve")
```

Comment: This will also work but we have lots of column so i think instead of restricting to the cells i will keep the number of cell out and only use column but your answer also works :)